# Find Wc (Angular cutoff frequency) from second order low pass filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have 2nd order low pass filter code for filtering data in Matlab GUI. To run this code I need to write value of wc(Angular cutoff frequency, rad/s), k(damping factor), and Sampling time(which matlab automatically read from file) in the text box then I have to click button filter and integral then it will filter from HPF to LPF.

=======================================================================================

```
function [ filtered_result_data ] = PT2_Filter( data_need_to_be_filtered, wc, k,   samplingtime )
    filtered_result_data(1) = data_need_to_be_filtered (1);
    filtered_result_data(2) = data_need_to_be_filtered (2);
    b0 = wc^2 *samplingtime^2; %* 0.0001^2;
    a1 = 2 * b0 - 8;
    a2 = b0 - 4 * k * wc *samplingtime + 4; %* 0.0001 + 4;
    for i = 3:length(data_need_to_be_filtered)
    filtered_result_data(i) = 1/a0 * ( b0 *( data_need_to_be_filtered(i)...
      + 2*data_need_to_be_filtered(i-1)+data_need_to_be_filtered(i-2) ) ...
      - a1 * filtered_result_data(i-1) -a2 * filtered_result_data(i-2));
    end
```

=======================================================================================

**Also I am using this code as PT2 filter in this code,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzO14.png) which is below**.

======================================================================================

```
    CEU_X=evalin('base','CEU_X');
    CEU_Y=evalin('base','CEU_Y');
    No_CEU_X=evalin('base','No_CEU_X');
    No_CEU_Y=evalin('base','No_CEU_Y');
    wc=evalin('base','wc');
    k=evalin('base','k');
    samplingtime=evalin('base','samplingtime');

    [row,col] = size(CEU_X);
    for i = 1:row
       for j = 1:col
            if isempty(CEU_X(i,j).file)
               CEU_X(i,j).data(1:8000) = 0;
               %break;
            end
            CEU_X(i,j).filtered_signal(1,:) = PT2_Filter(CEU_X(i,j).data,wc,k,samplingtime);
            CEU_X(i,j) = do_first_integral(CEU_X(i,j));
            CEU_X(i,j).absolut = abs(CEU_X(i,j).filtered_signal);
       end
    end

    [row,col] = size(CEU_Y);
    for i = 1:row
       for j = 1:col
            if isempty(CEU_Y(i,j).file)
               CEU_Y(i,j).data(1:8000) = 0;
               %break;
            end
            CEU_Y(i,j).filtered_signal(1,:) = PT2_Filter( CEU_Y(i,j).data,wc,k,samplingtime);
            CEU_Y(i,j) = do_first_integral( CEU_Y(i,j));
            CEU_Y(i,j).absolut = abs(CEU_Y(i,j).filtered_signal);
       end
    end

    [row,col] = size(No_CEU_X);
    for i = 1:row
       for j = 1:col
            if isempty(No_CEU_X(i,j).file)
               No_CEU_X(i,j).data(1:8000) = 0;
               %break;
            end
            No_CEU_X(i,j).filtered_signal(1,:) = PT2_Filter( No_CEU_X(i,j).data,wc,k,samplingtime);
            No_CEU_X(i,j) = do_first_integral( No_CEU_X(i,j));
            No_CEU_X(i,j).absolut = abs(No_CEU_X(i,j).filtered_signal);
       end
    end

    [row,col] = size(No_CEU_Y);
    for i = 1:row
       for j = 1:col
            if isempty(No_CEU_Y(i,j).file)
               No_CEU_Y(i,j).data(1:8000) = 0;
               %break;
            end
            No_CEU_Y(i,j).filtered_signal(1,:) = PT2_Filter( No_CEU_Y(i,j).data,wc,k,samplingtime);
            No_CEU_Y(i,j) = do_first_integral( No_CEU_Y(i,j));
            No_CEU_Y(i,j).absolut = abs(No_CEU_Y(i,j).filtered_signal);
       end
    end

    

    msgbox(['data has been filtered with wc = ',num2str(wc),' k = ',num2str(k)],'Analyse Msg','help');
```

=====================================================================================

If Any one know how can we find Wc(Angular cutoff frequency, rad/s) like reverse process of the code if we select different different frequency in Hz as we need, and show it into matlab workspace. So, Plase help me, if any one have solution like how to write both code to find Wc and show it in to matlab workspace.